# GIT not tracking files

Tags: git, github, aix

I have setup GIT on AIX 6.1 and am facing problems.

The sequence of steps I followed are as shown:

1. I create a folder.
2. Go into the folder and initialise the non-bare repository
3. Initialise the username and user email
4. Create a file named index.html with some data in the file.
5. Create a subfolder named newfolder
6. Go into the newly created folder.
7. Create a new file named index-2.html with some data in it.

After performing all the steps above and give the `git status` command I'm getting the foll result:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../index.html
#       ./
```

I understand that index.html in the above directory is getting displayed but why doesent index-2.html not getting displayed which is in the current directory.

The file index-2.html should also get tracked right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output shows two things that are currently untracked:

- `../index.html` – the `index.html` file in the parent folder
- `./` – the current folder, including all its contents

So it does detect that you have an untracked file, but because it does know nothing about its folder as well, it just shows the folder to accumulate all its content.

If you add your files and make Git track them, they will show up correctly:

```
git add index-2.html
git add ../index.html
```

Comment: But I did not add index.html in the parent directory.How did that show up in the list even when I did not add the file

Comment: The status output is always relative to your current directory. As you entered the subfolder (step 6), `index.html` is now in the parent of your current folder.

Answer (score 3):

It is tracking the folder ./ which means the current folder. git doesn't (correct me if I'm wrong), care about subfolders at all. Meaning if you have a repository with the folder foo, which is already in the repository. You add a subfolder bar in foo, and create a file foobar.txt in foo/bar. Then you will only get:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ./bar
```

Which means that if you had done cd .. before your git status command, you would get:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       index.html
#       newfolder
```

even though you have a file inside.

The reason for this is that git tracks content, not files. Since index2.html actually is a content of the folder newfolder, and you are not tracking newfolder, git doesn't know that index2.html exists.