# Unable to automatically track files using add -A; no errors thrown

Tags: git

I have added a couple of files to my project, when I try to stage them for a commit by running the `git add -A` (I also tried `git add --all',`git add .` , but all approaches led to the same outcome) I get a little dot on the cross button on the terminal (which I see every time I run any command),  but nothing else happen, even after waiting for 5 minutes.

When I run `git status`, I get a list of untracked files, which are all the files I recently added to my project and want to add. I tried looking for the answer and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340001/git-not-tracking-files) post, but there are too many files to manually add, so I am wondering if there is an alternate way to add the files, keeping in mind that `git add` isn't working for me?

**Update1:** As requested, here is the gitignore file:

```
# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace
# Android/IJ
#
.idea
.gradle
local.properties

# node.js
#
npm-debug.log
android-ndk-r11b
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm too low-ranked to comment on your question, but have you checked your .gitignore file(s)?

Comment: I did and didn't find anything unusual but I have pasted the contents above.

Comment: Your .gitignore looks fine. Have you tried `git add .` (`git add -A` = `git add . && git add -u`)? That should just track new files instead of adding updates from old ones. When you say you see the dot, do you mean your terminal hangs / is still processing the command? Have you tried tracking individual files to see if even that works? First step should always be to diagnose the scope of the problem.

Comment: I tried all the commands except `git add -u`, still didn't work.

Comment: Are you, technically speaking, able to `git add foo.bar` with just one file, or does that command also fail?

Comment: I am able to `git add foo.bar` successfully.

Comment: You can try `git add *`, and `git add * --force` (the latter ignores your .gitignore), which should recurse through the entire file tree of your repo if you're in the root dir, but barring those two, all I can think of is writing tree-traversing  bash script along the lines of [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924405/depth-first-search-in-bash-script-using-simple-data-structures) Sorry I couldn't help more, best of luck.